# import user input from TKinter button to a different .py module

Tags: python, button, tkinter, python-import

On `ticket.py` module i have a Tkinter frame; `value = Entry(frame)`, and on the same module I have a button where `command=exoutput`;

`def exoutput():
    print value.get()`

I would like to import the `value` to `othermodule.py` on the button command/ when I hit the button. 
Currently when I import, the `print` is generated from the `exoutput()` function, rather than from the `othermodule.py` file.

Suggestions on how to `print` the `value` on `othermodule.py`?

```
# ticket.py
from Tkinter import*

window = Tk()
window.title("Entry")

frame = Frame(window)
value = Entry(frame)

def exoutput():
    print value.get()

btnStage = Button(frame, text='ACTION', command=exoutput)
btnStage.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=2)
value.pack(side=LEFT)
frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

window.resizable(0, 0)
window.mainloop()
```

The other file, I've tried something like this;

```
# othermodule.py
import ticket

usersinput = ticket.value.get()
print usersinput
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I think you either need multi-threading, or swap your file contents. Nothing runs _after_ `mainloop` until the `Tk` instance is `destroy`ed.

Comment: Alternatively, you could instead structure your `ticket` py with OOP, and fetch GUI object from it by your `othermodule` to use it as you please. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470842/7032856.

Answer (score 0):

I think you either need multi-threading, or swap your file contents. Nothing runs after `mainloop` until the `Tk` instance is destroyed.

Alternatively, you could structure your `ticket.py` in OOP, and fetch GUI object from it by your `othermodule` to use it as you please. Below is an example:

`ticket.py`:

```
#import tkinter as tk
import Tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Entry")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        # create widgets
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.value = tk.Entry(self.frame)
        self.btn_stage = tk.Button(self.frame, text="ACTION")

        # widgets layout
        self.frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.btn_stage.pack(side='right', padx=2)
        self.value.pack(side='left')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Window()
    root.mainloop()
```

and `othermodule.py`:

```
import ticket


def put():
    global my_var_in_othermodule

    my_var_in_othermodule = ticket_GUI.value.get()
    ticket_GUI.destroy()


my_var_in_othermodule = ""

ticket_GUI = ticket.Window()
ticket_GUI.btn_stage['command'] = put
ticket_GUI.mainloop()

print(my_var_in_othermodule)

input()
```